Chi Squared Test of Association, Feature Engineering and Selection book, Chapter 2
In feat.engineering/stroke-tour by Kuhn & Johnson, there's a contingency table as below:

But I tried computing the chi-squared myself by hand and with a calculator and get 0.9818 with p-value ~0.32. Is this $p=0.42$ an errata in the book?

They've used Yates' continuity correction, you didn't.
The test statistic is discrete and you're using a continuous chi-squared approximation to it, so neither p-value is "correct"; but neither of you did anything wrong.
The simulated "exact" p-value obtainable from R - constructing the sampling distribution by conditioning on the margins, sampling from the distribution over the set of tables with those margins given independence - is in this case pretty much toward the middle of those two p-values.

Nothing to add/subtract to @Glen_b's answer; they used Yates correction, you did not. No one is wrong. Whether they should have or not, is another question... If you are using Yates continuity correction, why are you not using Fisher exact? (Yates correction is designed to make the p-value close to the "exact" test). That exact test gives a p-value of ,35, still not significant.
But I take strong exception to their conclusion! They fall in the common trap of saying that a non-significant result means the null is true. That is absolutely wrong!.
Here, for a blockage < 70%, more than half the subjects had no stroke; for subjects with a blockage >70%, more than half had a stroke. There is an indication that blockage is positively associated with stroke. All one can conclude from the non-signifiant result is that, if there truly was an association, the test was underpowered to find it. Stated differently, the test as conducted showed no association, but with more subjects it may. As a giggle, if one uses a sampe size 4x bigger (504 total subjects), assuming the exact same proportions, the test (2-sided) is significant (p=.0475, w/o Yates correction). Single sided tests would be significant sooner. But to conclude that blockage is not a good predictor of stroke is simply wrong. The study was not sufficiently powered to reach a definitive conclusion (or, generously, if there was an effect, it is smaller than what the study was powered for).
It is very bad science/statistics to conclude that the null is true, when all you did is failed to disprove the null; absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. If they wrote this, I would be careful about anything else they wrote...

I don't interpret their statement as "blockage has no effect", but "blockage is likely to have an effect that is irrelevant to a prediction task". Now, I wonder why they did not use a confidence/credible interval to illustrate their rationale instead of hypothesis testing, but hard to comment on a statement taken out of context.

@J-J-J , they wrote "blockage is not a good predictor", not "blockage is not a good enough predictor"... And as you pointed out they used a hypothesis test. Could have used a ROC plot, e.g., but getting a non-significant result from a hypothesis test only means that their sample size was too small... If they wanted to talk about effect size, then they should have mentioned which effect they would have considered "clinically significant". Non-significant hypothesis test does not imply "bad predictor".

They wrote "Blockage categorization alone is likely not a good predictor", which is not a final judgment on the relevance of this variable for prediction tasks, and hints to a more detailed analysis in later sections of the book. For this reason, I'd be much more careful about judging the book just from one paragraph, without knowing what they say before and after it.
